# Hide subview image once the view has loaded (using Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimageview, subview

Technologies: XCode6, iOS 8.2, Swift

When the view loads, I add an image:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    webView.delegate = self
    self.navigationController?.toolbarHidden = false;
    openLoadingPopup()
    if browserHistory.count < 1 {
        backButton.enabled = false
    }
    let imageName = UIImage(named: "image.png")
    let imageview = UIImageView(image: imageName)
    imageview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)
    self.view.addSubview(imageview)
}
```

And I want to remove that image here (if possible). Best way to do that?

```
 func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication()
        . networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
    closeLoadingPopup()
    if cacheURL {
        ++browserHistoryIndex
        browserHistory.insert(webView.request!.URL, atIndex: browserHistoryIndex)
        backButton.enabled = browserHistoryIndex != 0
        //forwardButton.enabled = browserHistoryIndex != browserHistory.count - 1
    }
    if webView.request!.URL == lastURL {
        cacheURL = true
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make imageView a property instead of a local variable, and use imageView.removeFromSuperview() in the webViewDidFinishLoad method.

Comment: How would I define imageView as a property? var imageView: UIImageView!   ?

Comment: @MichaelSebastian, yes, you would do that outside of any method.

Comment: imageView.image = UIImage(named: "image.png") ## <-- I'm getting error here ##
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)
        self.view.addSubview(imageView). Nevermind - I figured this out

Comment: Figured it out (with your help)! Thanks!